# Erros no Ruby aparecem porque?

Tags: ruby, socket, url, syntax-error, uri

**Objetivo** 
Adicionar (uri, url) com porta.

```
 # Ajuda por carlos-romero   
 # https://stackoverflow.com

 # Ajuda por mu-is-too-short
 # https://stackoverflow.com

require 'uri'
require 'socket'

url = 'file://C://'

 class Class1
    def fileProtocol( url )
        uri = URI(url) if scheme = uri.scheme
      puts fileProtocol(url)
    end
  end

 class Class2
     def fileProtocolPort( server )
         server = TCPServer.open(8080)
           for i in  0..5
           client = server.accept
             client.puts(Time.now.ctime)
            client.puts "Closing the connection. Bye!"
            client.close
            end
            end
            end
```

**ruby mostra esses errors**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       2: from main.rb:7:in `<main>'
>       1: from main.rb:7:in`open'
>   main.rb:7:in `initialize': Address already in use - bind(2) for nil port 8080 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)

Então, o que isso significa esses erros? Você pode me ajudar?

Comment: O que é esse if dentro da função? Por que ele tem dois "end"?

Comment: Esse if é scheme 'esquema url' ... Se 'If' é scheme 'esquema url'  igual  a uri.scheme  ... Bem uri = URI(url, server) é isso.

Comment: O 2 end 's eram para encerrar dentro do def ( url, server )

Comment: conseguiu resolver essa questão?